# Pandas Creating indicator variables from Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have the following dataframe:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df=pd.DataFrame()
>>> df['Food']=['Orange','Carrot','Apple','Pizza','Cake','Pretzel','Cauliflower']
>>> df
          Food
0       Orange
1       Carrot
2        Apple
3        Pizza
4         Cake
5      Pretzel
6  Cauliflower
>>>
```

And then I have the following dictionary with keys that are categories and values that are a list of values in that category:

```
>>> FoodClasses
{'Vegetable': ['Carrot', 'Cauliflower'], 'Fruit': ['Orange', 'Apple']}
>>>
```

I want to add columns to my dataframe for each of the two categories (Vegetable and Fruit) and have the columns populated with values indicating whether or not that value is in that category.

I currently do this by looping through each of the categories and get my desired result as such:

```
>>> for FoodClass in FoodClasses:
...     df[FoodClass]=df['Food'].isin(FoodClasses[FoodClass]).astype(int)
... 
>>> 
>>> df
          Food  Vegetable  Fruit
0       Orange          0      1
1       Carrot          1      0
2        Apple          0      1
3        Pizza          0      0
4         Cake          0      0
5      Pretzel          0      0
6  Cauliflower          1      0
>>>
```

Is there a better way to do this that doesn't involve looping through the dictionary?

Comment: This seems fine to me personally

Comment: looping through columns is generally OK, looping through rows is generally not ideal as most pandas methods are designed to work on entire columns at once (aka vectorized operations) and are MUCH faster than looping through rows.